# Interception @Finally and @Catch

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I was trying out a demo on Exception handling in controller using an interception `@Finally`.

I made an intentional `NullPointerException` in the controller and tried to catch the exception in the `@Finally` block.

When I tried this then it works:

```
@Finally
 static void log(Throwable e) {
   if( e == null ){
       Logger.info("Inside FInally: Action call was successful");
   } else{
       Logger.info("Inside Finally: Action call failed", e);
   }
 }
```

But if I try this the it does not work:

```
@Finally
static void log(NullPointerException e) {
   if( e == null ){
       Logger.info("Inside FInally: Action call was successful");
   } else{
       Logger.info("Inside Finally: Action call failed", e);
   }
 }
```

Again if I consider the `@Catch` interception then both the following works:

```
 @Catch(value = Throwable.class , priority = 2)
 public static void te(Throwable throwException){
    .....
 }

@Catch(value = NullPointerException.class , priority = 1)
public static void npe(Throwable throwNullPointerException){
    .....
 }
```

Why is the second scenario not working in `@Finally` interception? Is it a compulsion to use **only** `Throwable` superclass for any kind of exception rather than using any specific subclass exception?

Please let me know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online developer guide does not explicitly say that you cannot use specific Exception type. But considering the idea behind this **@Finally** intercetpion, I guess you are right; that is, **@Finally** only takes Throwable.

Let's think about it from this way, what if you have **multiple catch statements** in the method, only one catch will be triggered if there is an exception thrown. In this case, it would be confusing if the argument is **NPE** but the **DBConnectionTimeout**(for instance) is actually thrown. Therefore there is noway that your interceptor can work with other type of excpetion, nor you can have multiple @Finally interceptors.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) 1 confusing statement from your response is: `only one catch will be triggered if there is an exception thrown`. In Java, only one `catch` block will be executed when an exception is thrown inside a `try` block. But here I see a different behavior i.e. for a NPE, If I have two `@Catch`: 1) for Throwable.class 2) For NullPointer.class then I can see both are getting executed instead of only one (according to Java). What is the need for this? Is not it something different? Please explain your point of view.

Comment: I think the whole point of "@Finally" is to provide you a single entry for intercepting execution of finally block. In this case, considering that multiple "@Finally" is not allowed, in order to pass exception catched in try block, @Finally only takes top level interface, which is Throwable to prevent from missing out exception. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: surely the "@Catch" in play framework differs from "Catch" key word in java. Two "@Catch" are triggered because NPE is subclass of Throwable, therefor it satisfies both "@Catch" value. So, don't get confused about Catch block and @Catch interception, they are different things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I agree with your logic for having the `Throwable` in `@Finally` Interception. But 1 more confusion in your reply: `considering that multiple "@Finally" is not allowed` I can see that multiple `@Finally` blocks are allowed in a Controller class. Then why you mentioned this? Please explain

Comment: @WhoAmI, yes you are right about "multiple @Finally". Can you verify that all the methods with annotation "@Finally" are triggered at the end? I still don't think that the purpose of having multiple "@Finally" methods is to distinguish different types of Exception.

Comment: Yes, I have already verified that all the methods with annotation `@Finally` are triggered at the end.